# How to detect the font which is used in this heading?

Tags: fonts

this is a simple facebook page(just as an example) and I want to know what is the name of the font which is used for the heading("Introducing Graph Search");

I can see the source of the page in google chrome by using the "view source" option in chrome but I can't just find the exact font name;

[image]

Comment: Seems trebuchet ms :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inspector Computed Panel (Chrome)

```
font-family: 'Freight Sans Bold', 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use firefox plugin you may go for "font finder" plugin which gives good results on web pages.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/

Answer (score 1):

it's set in css file. And you should search style not only for class applied on this element you also sholud remember that css can use inheritance.
This font uses [facebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mkuta4ndabu25o/123.PNG)